# changing font size of nested lists in itemize and enumerate environment

Tags: xetex

I am using the following to change the font size of items at different levels in itemize list:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ChangeItemFont[3]{%
\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][]{%
  \beamer@ifempty{##1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
    \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
    \list
      {\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
      {\def\makelabel####1{%
          {%
            \hss\llap{{%
                \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}####1}}%
          }%
        }%
  \ifnum\@itemdepth=1\relax
    #1%
  \else
\ifnum\@itemdepth=2\relax
    #2%
  \else
  \ifnum\@itemdepth=3\relax
    #3%
  \fi%
  \fi%
  \fi%
  }
  \fi%
  \beamer@cramped%
  \raggedright%
  \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}}
\makeatother
```

But, this doesn't affect the enumerate lists. What changes do I need to perform so that I can also change the font size of enumerate at different level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't provide a [full MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), so this may not be at all what you're looking for, but it seems like you're using [beamer](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer).  If so, then you can change the font size of enumerate and itemize environments through the `itemize/enumerate body begin` family of keys as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\tiny}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\normalsize}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subsubbody begin}{\huge}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Subitem 2.1
    \item Subitem 2.2
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item subsubitem 2.2.1
      \item subsubitem 2.2.2
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: output]